# Creating incremental reports using Azure Tables

Tags: azure, report, storage, etag

I need to create incremental reports in the table storage. I need to be able to update the same records from several different worker role instances (different roles with several instances each).

My reports consist mainly of values that I need to **increment** after I parse the raw data I initially stored.

The optimistic solution I found is to use a retry mechanism: Try to update the record. If you get a 412 result code (you don't have the latest ETAG value), retry. This solution becomes less efficient and more costly the more users you have and the more data you need to update simultaneously (my case exactly).

Another solution that comes to mind is to have only one instance of one worker role that can possibly update any given record. This is very problematic because this means that I will by-design create bottlenecks in my architecture, which is the opposite of the scale I want to reach with Azure.

If anyone here has some best practices in mind for such a use case, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Most cloud storages (Table Storage is one of those) do not offer scalable writes on a single entity/blob/whatever. There is no quick-fix for this limitation, as this limitation comes from the core tradeoff that have being made to create cloud storage in the first place.

Basically, a storage unit (entity/blob/whatever) can be updated about once every 20ms, and that's about it. Having a dedicated worker or not will not change anything to this aspect.

Instead, you need to address your task from from a different angle. For counters, the most usual approach is the use of [sharded counters](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) (link is for GAE, but you can implement an equivalent behavior on Azure).

Also, another way to ease the pain to go for an asynchronous architecture ala [CQRS](http://abdullin.com/cqrs) where the performance constraints you put on the update latency of entities is significantly relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the approach needs re-architecture.  In order to ensure scalability and limit amount of contention, you want to make sure that every write can work optimistically by providing unique Table/PartitionKey/RowKey

If you need those values for reports to be merged together, have a separate process/worker that will post-aggregated/merge the records for reporting purposes.  You can use a queue or a timing mechanism to start aggregation/merging